# All of my Windows computers won't connect to the Internet (LAN or WiFi)

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, internet, lan

My **Windows** computers:

1. Desktop - connected to LAN. Error: LAN connection / Ethernet Adaptor may have a problem
2. Laptop - connected via WiFi Error: "Limited Access"
3. Laptop - connected via WiFi Error: "Limited Access"

All of my Windows computers are not able to connect to the Internet. The errors are written above.

The service team from my Internet Service Provider tried to connect their laptop to our LAN and WiFi, and both worked fine for them - so they assume that our problem is caused by a virus. The weird thing is, my Macbook, iPhone, iPad, and Nexus 7 can all connect to the Internet with no problems.

Also, it might be worth noting that I can boot into Windows 7 on my Macbook, and can connect to the Internet using this.

Any ideas on this? The only thing I remember doing lately that may have contributed to this problem is that I tinkered with our WiFi security settings (changed it from WPA2 to WPA-Personal) and changed the password. I've already changed the properties for all of my computers to set our connection to WPA-Personal.

Here are the things that have I have already tried (and failed):

- Disabling and enabling the LAN connection (desktop) and WiFi
  (laptop)
- Hard reset the router
- No changes in any proxy settings
- Reset the TCP/IP Winsock

I can't really pinpoint what virus this could be (if it really is a virus causing it) because it seems weird that it'd attack 3 computers - all of which have Antivirus programs, and 2 of which I don't even use that much. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: On laptops, have you completely removed the "remembered" wifi network profiles?

Comment: You write "The service team from our Internet Service Provider tried to connect their laptop to our LAN and WiFi, and both worked fine for them - so they assume that our problem is caused by a virus. " Really! They assume that!

Comment: Did they sugggest things like right clicking the network adaptor if win7 and clicking diagnose? or doign ipconfing /release and ipconfig /renew? Have you done -any- troubleshooting steps with them at all?

Comment: @barlop Hi! Over the phone, they asked me to disable and enable the LAN and WiFi. When that didn't work, they went here to troubleshoot for me. They clicked diagnose and all the stuff on the troubleshooting thing of Windows. No luck. They didn't do the ipconfig /release and renew though.. I did that on my own upon doing some research but that didn't help either. They said they assume it's a virus because they were able to connect their laptop to both Wifi and LAN and suggested that we reformat at least one of our computers to check if this was the case.

Comment: @barlop Reformatting is my last resort because I don't see what kind of virus would hit all 3 computers when 2 of them were off for like maybe over 2 months (or maybe I'm just not that updated with viruses these days haha!)

Comment: @brianadkins Hi! Yup, tried that. No luck :(

Comment: Do you get the same issues if you boot some Linux live distribution?

Comment: @and31415 Hi! I don't have Linux installed on any computer so I wouldn't know. Sorry!

Comment: @Mai It doesn't need to be installed, hence why it's called "live." You just need to get an ISO image (e.g. [here](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php), or [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)) and burn it to a DVD. As an alternative you can use a program like [tuxboot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxboot/) to create a bootable USB drive.

Comment: It is unlikely to be malware(what you are calling a virus), it's unlikely largely for reasons you mentioned. And nobody here has said to reinstall.

Comment: if you cant connect to lan then wlan/wifi is irrelevant. You could check event viewer.. you could load up wireshark and compare the packets from the problem comp to the one on the working one, to find clues.

Answer (score 1):

Try troubleshooting the connections
OR
Troubleshot the PPPOE settings or change them

hope this works as  well for you as it did for me

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Tried these but still can't access the Internet.